React component is not re rendering even though the parent's state changes
I have a form where i want to do input check as user enters input via onChange event.
I store user's input in a state variable in the container (call this the form component) and use the setter to trigger a re render of the children (call this the input component) with a message if the input is not acceptable.
When the form is mounted, i see that the input component renders, but even though i change the state of the form component and pass the state as a prop to the input component, it seems to me that the input component is not re rendered.
Any ideas why and how to fix this?
Here is a sample code:
  1 function RegistrationForm({setUserData, setCurrentView, coords}) {
  2   const [formData, setFormData] = useState(new Map([['regGender', 'erkek']]));
  3   const [messages, setMessages] = useState(new Map());
  4   const [areFieldsReady, setAreFieldsReady] = useState(false);
  5   const [isPhotoReady, setIsPhotoReady] = useState(false);
  6
  7   function handleChange({target}) {
  8     setFormData(prevFormData => {
  9       const formData = prevFormData.set(target.id, target.value)
 10       checkRegistrationForm(formData, setMessages, setAreFieldsReady); // Updates the messages state
 11       return formData;
 12     });
 13   }
 14
 15   function handleChangePhoto ({target}) {
 16     setFormData(prevFormData => prevFormData.set(target.id, target.files[0]));
 17     setIsPhotoReady(true);
 18   }
 19
 20   function handleRegisterClick(e) {
 21     e.preventDefault();
 22     if(!areFieldsReady || !isPhotoReady) {
 23       return;
 24     }
 25     formData.set('lat', coords.lat);
 26     formData.set('lng', coords.lng);
 27     registerUser(formData)
 28       .then(resObj => {
 29         localStorage.isLoggedIn = 'true';
 30         localStorage.pid = resObj.pid;
 31         localStorage.password = resObj.password;
 32         setUserData(resObj);
 33         setCurrentView('UserView');
 34       })
 35       .catch(error => alert(error));
 36   }
 37
 38   return (
 39     <div className='registrationForm'>
 40       <p>Email</p>
 41       <p>{messages.get('regEmail')}</p>
 42       <InputEmail id='regEmail' onChange={handleChange}
 43         value={formData.get('regEmail')} message={messages.get('regEmail')} />
/* Code continues */

I tried moving the paragraph element inside the input component to jsx in the form component and i still don't get a re render: the message is not printed. I checked via breakpoints that the messages Map is updated when the return is called.
